# Using CArchive::GetObjectSchema returns wrong value

Tags: carchive

I have a problem here. In my main application header file I have these definitions:

```
#define SOUNDROTA_VERSION_171801    171801 // 17.1.8 Beta 1
#define SOUNDROTA_VERSION_CURRENT   171801 // 17.1.8 Beta 1
```

In my application I have a `CObject` derived class which has this at the top:

```
IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CChristianLifeMinistryEntry, CObject, VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | SOUNDROTA_VERSION_CURRENT)
```

Things have always worked fine when using the schema value up until now. I admit that previously the values I was using were smaller, like `1707` for **17.0.7** but I was trying to factor in for beta versions too and thus larger numbers.

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    CObject::Serialize(ar);

    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {   // saving code
    else
    {   // loading code
    UINT uSchema = ar.GetObjectSchema();
        if (uSchema >= SOUNDROTA_VERSION_171801)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Booh"));
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I save a data file and then re-open it, the `uSchema` has a value of **40729**.

Why? `GetObjectSchema` returns a `UNIT` so why am I not getting the schema I specified?

## Update

If I use a value of `1718` then it returns that value.

Comment: Is there no one who can help with this? At the moment I have had to drop support for old file formats and use my own versioning mechanism which I am not happy about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the legacy sources of **MFC** and `CRuntimeClass` class, (which can be found in subfolders of Visual Studio), the version is serialised as a `WORD` value and `0xFFFF` is reserved. Therefore, it appears that version cannot be greater than `0xFFFE` (65534).